# Replacing Multiple Characters Including Backslash

Tags: characters

I am in a situation to replace many characters from a sentence. In the working example attached below, command **relaceB** replaces *backslash* and command **replaceA** replaces many other characters like **, /* etc. But I am unable to combine both the commands together to form a single new command (which replaces- *,/,\ etc). Does anybody know how to fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

%Removing other characters
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_azor_string_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \azor_replace_norsk:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_azor_string_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_azor_string_tl { / } { -- }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_azor_string_tl { ? } { -- }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_azor_string_tl { * } { --}
  \tl_use:N \l_azor_string_tl
 }
\NewDocumentCommand \replaceA { m }
 {
  \azor_replace_norsk:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%Removing backslash
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\replaceB}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \cC. } { \c{cs_to_str:N} \0 } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\replaceA{a/b*c} %Works

\replaceB{d\e} %Works

\replaceA{\replaceB{a/b*cd\e}} %Does not work
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean combining them as in `\replace` which does `\replaceA{\replaceB{#1}}` or as in you want them to work in this nested way?

Comment: @TeXnician, yes, a command which works in a nested way would be more suitable.

Comment: @TeXnician, in the third line, the output does not contain backslash (only "de") but the other characters (/,*) are not removed.

Comment: These commands are not expandable, and they don't expand their arguments, so they can't be easily nested. You could modify them to store their product in macro `\replaceresult`: `\replaceB{a/b*cd\e}` does not typeset but stores in `\replaceresult`. `\expandafter\replaceA\expandafter{\replaceresult}` will now act on that and the new  `\replaceresult` is what you want. you can also define them to expand once, so you don't need `\expandafter`. Also, simplest might be to define a third command `\replaceC` doing all your replacements at once, if you want to stick to your initial way of doing things

Answer (score 5):

Use `\regex_replace_all:nnN` to do all the business at the same time:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

%Removing other characters
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_azor_string_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \azor_replace_norsk:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_azor_string_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \cC. } { -- \c{cs_to_str:N} \0 } \l_azor_string_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { [/?\*] } { -- } \l_azor_string_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_azor_string_tl
 }
\NewDocumentCommand \replace { m }
 {
  \azor_replace_norsk:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\replace{a/b*c}

\replace{d\e}

\replace{a/b*cd\e?f*g}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, this works, but the backslash is just removed, not replaced by hyphen (--).

Comment: @Ashok Fixed so also the backslash becomes `--`